# How to highlight text in epub like ibooks app

Tags: iphone, ios, epub

I need to highlight text in epub book,when user selects the text,i can get the text,what the user has selected,but i need to highlight,the text permanently  what user selected,thanks,any help will ne appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing built in to iOS that will do this. Some broad techniques that might work:

- If you're showing the book in a web view, you might be able to wrap that area in a `span` and style it to create a highlight.
- If you're using Core Text, you could draw the highlight in directly, either before or after drawing the text. (Your choice will decide how the highlight affects non-black text.)
- You could add a transparent view over the text that draws in the highlight.

As for adding highlight-related items to the selection menu, see [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955354/showing-custom-menu-on-selection-in-uiwebview-in-iphone). You probably won't be able to get icons in the menu like Apple does, though; that seems to be a private API. You could probably override the whole menu system if you want something closer to Apple's look, but that'll be quite a bit of work.

Comment: HI Brent,thanks for your response,at present i am showing this is webview,can u give me any idea how to wrap area with span using java script,any useful link.

Comment: [This post on the DOM Selection object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328718/wrapping-a-selected-text-node-with-span) might be a good starting point.