# Can't disable the copy/define selection menu in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I know this is one of the most FAQs. As a matter of fact, I found the link below:

[Disabling user selection in UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995210/disabling-user-selection-in-uiwebview)

but I still can't remove the copy and define items from the menu selection. I just want my 'Quick' and 'Another' item to show in the menu. Can any one show me a way? Thank you for your time. Here is my code and screenshot.

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{


    if (action == @selector(quick:)) {

        NSLog(@"my quick view");
        return YES;

    }else if (action == @selector(another:)){

        NSLog(@"my another view");
        return YES;

    }else if (action == @selector(copy:) ||
        action == @selector(paste:)||
        action == @selector(cut:) ||
        action == @selector(define:) )
    {
        return NO;
    }

    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];

}
```

[image]

Comment: For more info, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/2955354/49485.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to fix your problem, change `define:` to `_define:` to remove the relating option.

However, `_define:` is a function in Apple's private API (because of `_`), you can't use them in your product if you want to release them on App Store.

However, in terms of your `copy:` option, your `canPerformAction` should remove it.

FYI, here I attach a list of private API functions, which canPerformAction will call:

`_promptForReplace:`

`_showTextStyleOptions:`

`_define:`

`_addShortcut:`

`_accessibilitySpeak:`

`_accessibilitySpeakLanguageSelection:`

`_accessibilityPauseSpeaking:`

Therefore, if you want to remove any function above, you have to create a customized menu bar. This video below should help you do the trick:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SB7w8JEJSrc

GOOD LUCK!

**EDIT:**

Here is your solution:

```
-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{


if (action == @selector(quick:)) {

    NSLog(@"my quick view");
    return YES;

}else if (action == @selector(another:)){

    NSLog(@"my another view");
    return YES;

}

return NO;

}
```

Comment: Here's the API calls I got when viewing a PDF:

 - Action is: cut:
 - Action is: select:
 - Action is: selectAll:
 - Action is: paste:
 - Action is: delete:
 - Action is: _promptForReplace:
 - Action is: _showTextStyleOptions:
 - Action is: _addShortcut:
 - Action is: _accessibilitySpeak:
 - Action is: _accessibilitySpeakLanguageSelection:
 - Action is: _accessibilityPauseSpeaking:
 - Action is: makeTextWritingDirectionRightToLeft:
 - Action is: makeTextWritingDirectionLeftToRight:

Comment: Basically, you are prohibited to include ANY private API, which starts their name with an underscore `_`. If you happen to have them as part of your code, it will be certainly rejected by App Store.

Comment: APPLE's own private APIs, more precisely

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this one in this method .....

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)theWebView
{
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.style.webkitTouchCallout='none'; document.body.style.KhtmlUserSelect='none'"];
}
```

I hope it helps you...

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but this kills the whole thing. I want my items 'Quick' and 'Another' to show up, disabling the copy and define.