# Alternative approach instead of double click on iPad iOS devices

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

Is there any alternative idea for double click/tag issue for iPad|iOS devices?

I have a JavaScript web application functionality in which double click event is binded to some text paragraph; If the user double click on any of the word within this paragraph, a popup gets opened with a short description relevant to that word.

Now, this work perfectly on desktop browsers, but for iPad|iOS devices well it does not as due to lack of support for double click/tap event.

1st solution could be avoiding double click event for iPad|iOS devices with some design approach;
2nd solution could be disable the doubleclick/zoom on the iPad with viewport user-scalable no; But I am still in process of identifying any side effects of doing this. User won't able to zoom the site but its fine with the requirements.

Could anyone please suggest me Good or better solutions? I am open to all types of solution as I can restrict the solution to iPad|iOS devices.

Comment: Try this brilliant answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3596414/1463604